# error in setting up chef-shell

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to setup chef shell for the very first time.
I created chef_shell.rb in same path as knife.rb and copied the values of "node_name", client_key and chef_server_url from knife.rb to chef_shell.rb.

When I run `chef-shell -z` from my `.chef` directory, I get this error.
Any help?

```
.......Creating a new client identity for Username-MacBook-Pro.local using the validator key.

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "Username-MacBook-Pro.local"
================================================================================

Platform:
---------
x86_64-darwin13

epic fail!

/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb:74:in `assert_destination_writable!': I can't write your private key to /etc/chef/client.pem - check permissions? (Chef::Exceptions::CannotWritePrivateKey)
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb:54:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/client.rb:620:in `register'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell/shell_session.rb:219:in `rebuild_node'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell/shell_session.rb:55:in `block in reset!'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell/shell_session.rb:101:in `loading'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell/shell_session.rb:54:in `reset!'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell.rb:127:in `session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell.rb:136:in `init'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/shell.rb:65:in `start'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/bin/chef-shell:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/chef-shell:57:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/chef-shell:57:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It says

> I can't write your private key to /etc/chef/client.pem - check permissions?

So it seems that it didn't pick up the settings for your private key. Are you sure that it will look for `chef_shell.rb`?

In doubt try

```
chef-shell -c chef_shell.rb -z
```